# Custom RazorViewEngin don't execute overriden CreateView

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to create a custom view engine to look for views based on a specific virtual path based on modulen ame/assembly name. The plan is to be able to install modules containing their own separate views and controllers.

I have a structure to load and configure things when my application starts upp. In my MVC Initializer module i clear all view engines and then add my own custom view engine.

However the overriden CreateView never execute when i navigate to a controller action. Findview do execute and i currently just return base.FindView(..., ..., ...).

My current class inherit RazorViewEngine and i set my new strings for all locations based on my needs and using %1 as my assembly name holder in those strings.
In my CreateView i then replace %1 with the assembly name of the controller.

The work is based on the information from http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/archive/2011/06/27/view-engine-with-dynamic-view-location.aspx.

But as i said the problem is create view never executed so it never finds a view since the view locations contains %1 and not the assembly name.

Worth mentioning is i run a asp.net MVC 5, c# .NET 4/4.5 site.

Comment: Have you overridden the `FileExists` method? You would need to override it as in the article, replacing %1 before calling the base implementation

Comment: Looks like that was my mistake here, not override the FileExist method. This have been driving me mad for days now. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A stupid mistake like not override the FileExist method made this not working.